# Making sections of PHP dynamic while page caching using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a function that displays 4 random businesses. It works great, except that when we turn on page caching, it stops being dynamic. How can I make just this one section of my site dynamic using javascript so upon every page reload it displays 4 new random entries.

Site is using WordPress, and the WP Super Cache plugin.

Comment: You make an ajax request for it. i.e. `$('.whatever).load('/just/my/random/business/response.html')`. Or something similar. For something resembling an detailed answer you need to ask a detailed question.

Comment: just like @AD7six said, you need ajax, if you have problems implementing it you can post the function that is currently showing the businesses